# SonarQube c/c++ community plugin error

Tags: c++, c, sonarqube

I am new to sonarQube. I installed the C/C++ community plugin following [this procedure](https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx).

Sonar installed on my windows machine as sonar 5.1 and runner is 2.4. I'm getting the following error when I try to analyse a C/C++ project..

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Total time: 9.944s

Final Memory: 16M/78M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution

ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar

ERROR: Caused by: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'cpp'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see the plugin in Sonar settings?
Try going to the Update Center and install any updates to the plugin if any.
Otherwise open the sonar project properties and remove/comment out sonar.language property if you have it? Then try again.
If the above doesn't work then share the part of log (available at \sonarqube-5.x\logs\sonar.log) that shows the error received. It may give a clue on this error.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep.. I uncommented the sonar.language in properties file now i m getting a new error... the new error is as follows:   ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Language of file 'src/HelloWorld.cpp' can not be decided as th
e file matches patterns of both sonar.lang.patterns.c++ : **/*.cxx,**/*.cpp,**/*
.cc,**/*.c,**/*.hxx,**/*.hpp,**/*.hh,**/*.h and sonar.lang.patterns.cpp : **/*.c
c,**/*.cpp,**/*.cxx,**/*.c++,**/*.hh,**/*.hpp,**/*.hxx,**/*.h++,**/*.ipp

Comment: Also i ll paste the log file.. pls help me out if you know more about it...    web[o.s.u.c.UpdateCenter] The plugin 'csharp' version : 4.0 has not been found on the update center.
web[o.s.u.c.UpdateCenter] The plugin 'css' version : 1.2 has not been found on the update center.
2015.08.27 10:46:49 INFO  web[o.s.u.c.UpdateCenter] The plugin 'cxx' version : 0.9.3 has not been found on the update center.

Comment: web[o.s.u.c.UpdateCenter] The plugin 'java' version : 3.0 has not been found on the update center.
web[o.s.u.c.UpdateCenter] The plugin 'scmgit' version : 1.0 has not been found on the update center.
web[o.s.u.c.UpdateCenter] The plugin  web[o.s.u.c.UpdateCenter] The plugin 'visualstudio' version : 1.2 has not been found on the update center.

Comment: Hi Madhura, By looking at the copy of your sonar log it seems that the c++ community plugin as well as few others are not installed on your machine. You should really get log like -

Comment: web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Install plugins
web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Core / 5.1.2 / 2a52a7106b2bfbd659c591c2d6fc09ad0ab2db5c
web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Email notifications / 5.1.2 / 2a52a7106b2bfbd659c591c2d6fc09ad0ab2db5c
web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin C# / 4.1 / b6ed44f09b52ed5aa32ad6bcfbf32cce77385ea7
web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin C++ (Community) / 0.9.4-SNAPSHOT / 0
web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Java / 3.4 / b70a82fcfbd4e4ae815fcb523252e6a7c769d676

Comment: Do you see the information about C++ (Community) [cxx] plugin v 0.9.3 or 0.94  when you go to Update Center / Installed plugins? You should also see other plugins that are installed? If not I suggest you retry installing the C++ community plugin as per instructions https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/wiki/Installation

Comment: You can also post your sonar-runner log, that may provide additional clues.

Comment: Hello Sandeep, I get c/c++(community) as shown in  github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/wiki/Installation after i downloaded and pasted the jar file in  SONAR\sonarqube\extensions\plugins\ floder when i try to analyse the C/c++ project I get the above mentioned error...

Comment: By sonar-runner log I meant the output of sonar-runner executable. You can either copy paste it or upload the output to google drive or some other shared server where I can have a look. It looks like the plugin is either not installed or not being loaded for some reason.

Comment: Hi sandeep, plz share ur email id so tat i can send you the error that I m getting.... thanks in advance

Comment: Here is my mangled email address that you will need to unmangle before sending email to me. Sorry to do this - don't want to invite unnecessary spam - myfirstnameDOTdDOTmylastnameATgmailDOTcom